# Microsoft-Word for Mac starts every new doc with columns

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, templates

I'm using Word for Mac (2017 or so), and it started opening every new document with columns. Then, whenever I start a new document - I have to go to

Format -> Columns and set "One column".

Every time I start a new doc, over again...

Any way to force MSWord to start every new document with one column? I tried to find it in the template, alas, I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a new blank document and things immediately go wrong,
suspect a corrupt Normal Template.

The default normal template file is called `Normal.dotm`.
To reinitialize it, rename it, and Word will recreate it anew.

I'm not sure where this template is stored on the Mac, so just search for
"Normal.dotm".
It might be found in
`~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/Normal.dotm`
(but this location might have changed).